# nginx: [emerg] unknown "root" variable

Tags: nginx, easy-engine

I am using easyengine and suddenly nginx is not reloading. I went to the log and nginx -t, its saying nginx: [emerg] unknown "root" variable and it failed to test. My sites are down. Is there anyone to help?

Comment: Whole stackoverflow comes to the rescue.But you need at least share your nginx.conf

Comment: It looks like you have a variable called `$root` which has not been defined.